# gtk: detect click on a cell in a TreeView

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I'm displaying some data as a TreeView. How can I detect a click on a particular tree-view cell, so that I know which column of which row was clicked on?

This is what I want to do, so maybe there's a better way: Part of the data is a series of True/False values indicating a particular set of options. For example, the options might be picking any of the options "Small, Medium, Large, X-Large" to be display. If the user selects `"Small"` and `"Large"`, then the cell should display `"Small, Large"`. I don't want to give each a separate column since there are actually like 20 options, and only 2 or 3 will be selected at any point.

When the user clicks on the cell, I want to display a pop-up with a bunch of checkboxes. The user can then select what s/he wants and submit the changes, at which point the cell's value should be updated.

The easiest way I thought of doing this would be to just detect a click (or a double-click) on the cell. Then I could pop up the window, and have the submit button of the window do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `row-activated` signal is sent when a GTK TreeView row is double-clicked.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that this answered the "How can I detect a click on a particular tree-view cell, so that I know which column of which row was clicked on?" question, since the signal is **row-activated** and doesn't obviously indicate the column.  The [docs for row-activated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated) describe the user function, which gets passed the tree view and path (enough to determine the row), the column and any user data.

Answer (score 0):

Ah from [this grea tutorial](http://scentric.net/tutorial/sec-misc-get-renderer-from-click.html) and [the API docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#signal-gtktreeview--row-activated), I can just connect to the `row-activated` event, which will give me all the information I need.